# What are my options to prevent duplicate code in Java in my case

Tags: java, duplicates

I got about 6 classes that are doing 'almost' the same with different values. I'll give two classes and an example below and then describe what i'm doing.

```
    public class AttributeRangeRule implements Template {
    @Override
    public String writeTemplate(BusinessRule businessRule) throws Exception {

        String link = TemplateReader.getInstance().getLinkToQuery(businessRule.getBusinessRuleTypeCode());
        String template = TemplateReader.getInstance().readQuery(link);
        ST templateFixer = new ST(template);
        templateFixer.add("code", businessRule.getBusinessRuleTypeCode());
        templateFixer.add("attribute_table", businessRule.getListOfTables().get(0).getName());
        templateFixer.add("operator", businessRule.getOperator().getName());
        templateFixer.add("range_min", businessRule.getListOfValues().get(0).getValue());
        templateFixer.add("range_max", businessRule.getListOfValues().get(1).getValue());
        templateFixer.add("attribute_column", businessRule.getListOfColumns().get(0).getName());
        templateFixer.add("error", businessRule.getErrorMessage());
        templateFixer.add("GreaterOrEqual", ">=");
        templateFixer.add("LessOrEqual", "<=");
        templateFixer.add("LessThen", "<");
        templateFixer.add("GreaterThen", ">");
        String templateDLL = templateFixer.render();
        return templateDLL;

    }
}


public class AttributeCompareRule implements Template {
    @Override
    public String writeTemplate(BusinessRule businessRule) throws Exception {

        String link = TemplateReader.getInstance().getLinkToQuery(businessRule.getBusinessRuleTypeCode());
        String template = TemplateReader.getInstance().readQuery(link);
        ST templateFixer = new ST(template);
        templateFixer.add("code", businessRule.getBusinessRuleTypeCode());
        templateFixer.add("attribute_table", businessRule.getListOfTables().get(0).getName());
        templateFixer.add("operand", businessRule.getOperator().getName());
        templateFixer.add("compare_with", businessRule.getListOfValues().get(0).getValue());
        templateFixer.add("error", businessRule.getErrorMessage());
        String templateDLL = templateFixer.render();
        return templateDLL;

    }
}
```

templateFixer.add("code..") is for example duplicate. They are written the same in both classes but the value is different.

I have different classes with different implementation of the method writeTemplate(). As you can see AttributeRangeRule is different from AttributeCompareRule. This code is writting a query for me. Intellij is telling me that the code is duplicate even if the values arent unique. I have no idea how to solve this issue. How can i solve this issue, since duplicate code isnt the best to have in your code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is probably better asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but please remember to check [their rules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting.

Comment: Thanks dear, i'll have to wait 40 minutes to post there. I didn't know about that platform. Thanks. Hope someone here can find a solution aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to take advantage of **OOPS** concepts here and use `inheritance` here

You can create a base class named `AttributeRule` that overrides `writeTemplate()` method and put all the redundant code in there and have this class be extended by your subclasses i.e. `AttributeCompareRule` and `AttributeCompareRule`

Here's the conceptual idea and some snippets

```
public class AttributeRule implements Template {

    @Override
    public String writeTemplate(BusinessRule businessRule) throws Exception {
        String link = TemplateReader.getInstance().getLinkToQuery(businessRule.getBusinessRuleTypeCode());
        String template = TemplateReader.getInstance().readQuery(link);
        ST templateFixer = new ST(template);
        templateFixer.add("code", businessRule.getBusinessRuleTypeCode());
        templateFixer.add("attribute_table", businessRule.getListOfTables().get(0).getName());
    }
}

public class AttributeCompareRule extends AttributeRule {

    @Override
    public String writeTemplate(BusinessRule businessRule) throws Exception {
        super.writeTemplate(rule);
        // Custom class code here
        templateFixer.add("operand", businessRule.getOperator().getName());
        templateFixer.add("compare_with", businessRule.getListOfValues().get(0).getValue());
        templateFixer.add("error", businessRule.getErrorMessage());
        String templateDLL = templateFixer.render();
        return templateDLL;
    }
}

public class AttributeRangeRule extends AttributeRule {
     super.writeTemplate(rule);
    // Custom class code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Pankaj. This will help me for sure.

Comment: I just noticed that in the custom class code section i cant continue doing templateFixer.add(etc), templateFixer doesnt excists, but should be there since its declared in the base class AttributeRule

Comment: You can return the instance of `ST` as a return type from the base class method, and work upon that in the child classes. Let me know if you couldn't figure it out and need help.

Comment: Thanks once again, i did exactly what you said and it works fine now.